# How can I check that a text file has at least 1 character

Tags: python

I have a text file how can I check in python that the text file has at least 1 number or alphabetic character and not just white spaces.

Comment: If any character other than whitespace counts, use `if open(filename).read().strip():`  You should probably put it in a `with` statement, though: `with open(filename) as open_file: if open_file.read().strip():`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did. I read the file putting the data into the string `data`. Then I used `data.strip()` to remove the leading and trailing whitespace. Then I checked to see if there is anything left from `data.strip()`. If there is you have characters in the file, if not your file has only whitespace or is completely empty.

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as file:
    data = file.read()

if data.strip():
    print("empty")
else:
    print("full")
```